# Svelte Reactivity Declaration Not Firing When Value is Set to False

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

```js
let isActive = false
let menuOpened = false

on:onMount(() => {
    rootBtn.style.width = btnWidth
})

$: isActive && handleActiveChange()

export function setActiveState(activeState) {
    isActive = activeState
}
function handleActiveChange() {

    if(isActive) {
        rootBtn.classList.add("active")
        animateOpen()
    } else {
        rootBtn.classList.remove("active")
        animateClose()
    }
}
```

Parent Component:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import CrusadeCards from "./crusadeCards.svelte";
    import MenuDropdown from "./menuDropdown.svelte";
    let battlesTab:HTMLDivElement, cardsTab:HTMLDivElement
    let battlesBtn:HTMLButtonElement, cardsBtn:HTMLButtonElement
    let cardDropdown:MenuDropdown
    let cardDropWidth = '125px'
    
    on:onMount(() => {
     
    })

    function battlesClicked() {
        cardsTab.style.display = "none"
        cardDropdown.setActiveState(false)

        battlesBtn.classList.add("active")
        battlesTab.style.display = "block"  
    }
    function addNewCard() {
        cardDropdown.animateClose()
        cardsTab.style.display = "block"
    }
    function cardsClicked() {
        battlesBtn.classList.remove("active")
        battlesTab.style.display = "none"
        cardsTab.style.display = "block"

        if(cardDropdown.getActiveState()) {
            if(cardDropdown.isOpen()) {
                cardDropdown.animateClose()
            } else {
                cardDropdown.animateOpen()
            }
        } else {
            cardDropdown.setActiveState(true)
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="mainInterfaceDiv">
    <div class="tabs">
        <button class="tabLink active" on:click={battlesClicked} bind:this={battlesBtn}>Battles</button>
        <MenuDropdown on:click={cardsClicked} rootBtnText="Crusade Cards" bind:this={cardDropdown} btnWidth={cardDropWidth}>
            <button class="dropMenuBtn" on:click={addNewCard}>New Card</button>
            <button class="dropMenuBtn">Two</button>
            <button class="dropMenuBtn">Three</button>

        </MenuDropdown>
    </div>

    <div id="battlesTab" class="tabContent battlesTab" bind:this={battlesTab}>
        Battles Go Here
    </div>
    <div id="cardsTab" class="tabContent" bind:this={cardsTab}>
        <CrusadeCards/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm calling setActiveState from the parent component to set the variable isActive to false and the reactive function does not fire. It works fine when setActiveState is called with true as the value however, so the function is working just not with false as a value? Is this a Svelte thing or is my reactive declaration not right?

Thank you!

Comment: could you show the parent component for context pls?

Comment: Added to original post!

Comment: can you put the entire components? Not just the context of the script tags... Like where is `cardDropdown` defined inside of the parent?

Comment: Sure, I was just worried it was a little long.

Comment: The `on:` before `onMount` is redundant, it creates a labeled statement and does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just wrong:

```js
$: isActive && handleActiveChange()
```

`&&` only evaluates the right side if the left is true.

Should be:

```js
$: isActive, handleActiveChange()
```

You can also have whole code blocks in reactive statements, so you could just not have an extra function:

```js
$: {
    if (isActive) {
        rootBtn.classList.add("active")
        animateOpen()
    } else {
        rootBtn.classList.remove("active")
        animateClose()
    }
}
```

Also, one generally should not manipulate DOM elements directly (like setting classes), that can e.g. be done using [`class:` directives](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#class-name). There are also directives for setting styles and in both cases you can also just interpolate into the respective attributes.

You should only *very* rarely need `bind:this`.